# STRING TO HEX how to add in a vector ob bytes?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
string s =   "2563MNBJP89256666666685755854";
            Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(s);
            string hex = "";
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                int c=b;
                hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(c.ToString()));
            }
```

It prints the hex values . How can I add it in a vector ob bytes like this?

```
new byte [0x32,0x35..]
```

`In hex I have : 323536...`.and so on. The next step is `to add then in a byte[] vector in the following format 0x32,0x35..and so on; How to do this?`

THX

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575468/string-to-byte-array for the c++ part

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to use this site...

Comment: do you mean an array of bytes? do you mean base64? do you mean another string of Hexidecimal numeral characheters?

Comment: yes an array og bytes that contains hexa values

Comment: Hm, could you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert from string to byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041381/how-to-convert-from-string-to-byte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't `bytes` already the list of bytes you want?

Comment: how to chech that? how to print the bytes values?

Comment: No it's not the same. The values are different:).

Comment: in s the results are: 50,53,54.. and in hex: 32,35,36 and so on

Comment: in s the results are in char! and in hex the results are in hexa values.

Comment: @daniel: Those are the same numbers. The first list is just represented in decimal while the second one is in hexadecimal.

Comment: I want the results in hexadecimal. How to convert them?

Comment: @daniel: Isn't that what your loop is doing? Converting them? I think you're confused as to what a number is. And judging by the comments on your first post you, it's not going to be worth my time to explain to you what a number is.

Comment: I am doing an encryption:). The result is different if i send encoding.getBytes(string) or if i send new byte[]{0x32,0x35..}. Where string is the string I want to have in hexadecimal

Comment: @daniel: I trust you will not be asking this question again, now that you have an accepted answer for it? Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here. If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6042016/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 0):

C#: `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test")`

Comment: it's not the same thing. i've tested it:)

Comment: What is not the same? You get the byte values associated with each character.

Answer (score 0):

For `C#` you could try

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(strVar);//strVar is the string variable
```

Comment: is there a link for an converter in ASCII, string, bytes and others? I knoe there was one..but i just can;t find the link

Answer (score 0):

in C# you can use [Encoding.GetBytes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx)